# Error trying to update macOS Mojave

Tags: macos, mojave

I have the problem shown below when I try the update macOS:

[image]

I restarted the computer but I still have the same error. I tried to release the PRAM but it doesn't work. I don't know why I can't update. I try to update from macOS 10.14.6 to 10.14.6. I think maybe is a minor update because I also updated my MBP normally without any problem.

Comment: Or you could try downloading "manually." The updates can be found here https://support.apple.com/downloads/macos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest 10.14.6 has sometimes its quirks to install.
I suggest to uncheck "automatically keep my mac up to date".

Download the COMBO update and install it,
https://support.apple.com/kb/DL2010?locale=en_US

Comment: Thank you. I already update my computer manually.